# how can i use main class variable in extendeded class

Tags: php, class

```
class a{

$array = array();

}
class b extends a{


**I need to get that array here !**

}
```

I'm not familiar with oops concept so please somebody help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
   class a
   { 

      public $_array = array(); 

   } 

   class b extends a
   { 

      public function getArray()
      {
         return $this->_array;
      }

   } 


   $x = new b();
   echo $x->_array;
   echo $x->getArray();
```

And read up on [visibility in classes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php), it'll help understand when something is accessible from a child class, or only from the parent

Answer (score 0):

You just read property as it would be in child class

```
<?
    class a {
        var $array = array(1,2,3);
    }

    class b extends a {
    }

    $b = new b();
    print_r ($b->array); // prints array
?>
```

See [online](http://ideone.com/kZzqQ).

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your array as public or protected property of your class a

```
class a {
  protected $array = array();
}

class b extends a {
   public function __construct() {
     $this->array = array('a', 'b', 'c');
   }
}
```

There are three visibility levels of properties & methods:

1. public. It means that property is visible outside the class
2. protected. This property will be visible in the class and its children (class that extend this one)
3. private. This property will be visible only from the class where property is defined.